# Is it normal that shifting from first to second gear requires side pressure

Tags: manual-transmission

Previously I had car with 5 gear transmission. Switching from 1st to 2nd was just move down. Now I have another car with 6 gear transmission. If I forget to add same pressure to the left I end with 4th gear engaged. It very similar to way the 5th gear is expected to operate. Is this normal or transmission is faulty (it works like that since it was new)?

The 5 gear car is Renault Thalia and The 6 gear is Fiat 500l

Comment: Maybe it was your first car that was faulty... It's fine, stop overthinking it, just drive it.

Comment: It's fine.  Some cars (Corvette and others) force a first-fourth shift under light throttle for better fuel economy numbers.

Comment: I'd say its normal.  The shifter wants to 'center' itself when its in neutral.  Your previous' transmission / linkage may had been a bit more worn out.  Also, the shifter is 4 slots wide now where it was previously 3.

Comment: Not all transmissions and shift mechanisms are the same. Maybe if you told us what make and model we can determine (not guess) whether the behavior is normal or not.

Comment: @CharlieRB I added specific models

Comment: Yeah I had this problem when driving my father's 6 speed MX-5. It's just getting used to it. If it really bugs you and you think their could be an issue you could have the gear linkages looked at. They're polyurethane bushes (on some cars) that can wear out, but your's is a pretty new car so I highly doubt it.

Comment: My 6 speed MINI doesn't require side pressure, but I don't think anything's wrong with your new car. It's just a different transmission design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I was taught to change gear from first to second or back again was to angle the back of my hand towards to myself, then push away and up/down.

Every car I've driven (UK) has required this to change from 1st to 2nd, so I would say it's perfectly normal.